# How to close accordion element before opening next?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('caption').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

How to close accordion element before opening next?

Comment: You will need to supply some more information before anyone can help you with this one. Set up a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net for starters so we can look at your code.

Comment: @will http://jsfiddle.net/yF9bB/1/ see this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('caption').nextAll().hide();  -- This hides the content when dom is ready
    $('caption').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```